# Challenges with Content Security Policy (CSP) in ASP.NET Core Application: Docker Deployment and Missing Response Headers

Tags: asp.net, docker, content-security-policy

I've implemented a Content Security Policy (CSP) in my ASP.NET Core application, but it's not working as expected when deployed to my stage environment, which includes Docker, ECS, and load balancing in the process. Even when testing locally with Docker Desktop, I couldn't find the CSP header in the response. Has anyone encountered a similar situation or have suggestions on how to troubleshoot this issue? Any insights would be appreciated!

I have an ASP.NET Core web application where I've implemented Content Security Policy (CSP) using the following code snippet in my layout.cshtml file:

This setup works perfectly fine on my local machine on both debug and release mode. when I check the response headers, I can see CSP.

> [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0iSUy.png)

However, when I deploy the application to my stage environment, which involves Docker, ECS (Elastic Container Service), and load balancing, the CSP doesn't seem to work as expected.

To investigate, I suspected Docker and tested the application on Docker Desktop locally. Surprisingly, I couldn't find the CSP header in the response headers, even on my local machine.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FslWQ.png)

Has anyone encountered a similar situation, or does anyone have suggestions on how to troubleshoot and overcome this issue? I'm particularly interested in understanding why the CSP headers aren't being transmitted, especially when using Docker, and how to ensure their proper delivery in the deployment environment.

Thank you for any insights or assistance you can provide!

Comment: Hi, using images for code or errors causes a lot of problems. Use images only to illustrate graphical issues. Please read [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/7353417).  Thank you